# Here is this pyramid. Find a specific angle by knowing its base's side and angle, and altitude of the pyramid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, angle

> A pyramid $MABCD$ with $ABCD$ being a rhombus, and $MM_1$ being its altitude is such that $M_1$ lies on $AC$, and $AM_1 : M_1C = 1 : 3$. Knowing that $AB=a$, $\angle BAD=\alpha < 90^\circ$, and $MM_1=a$, find the angle between planes $(ABM)$ and $(CDM)$.

My attempt of the solution is the following:

As $M$ is a common point of two planes, we can drop perpendiculars from it: $MK\perp AB$ and $ML\perp CD$, and then find the angle between them. This is how we do it:

1. We find the diagonals of the rhombus:

$AC=2a\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$

$BD=2a\sin\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$

2. As $AM_1 : M_1C = 1:3$, then consider $AM_1=x, M_1C=3x$. Then $AC=4x$. Thus:
   $$\begin{align*}
       AC &= AM_1+M_1C\\
       2a\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2} &= x+3x \\
       2a\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2} &= 4x \\
       x &= \dfrac{a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}
   \end{align*}$$

Therefore, $AM_1=\dfrac{a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$ and $M_1C=\dfrac{3a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$.

3. We can now find hypotenuse $AM$ by applying Pythagorean Theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
    AM
    &= \sqrt{MM_1^2 + AM_1^2} \\
    &= \sqrt{a^2+\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)^2} \\
    &= \sqrt{a^2+\dfrac{a^2}{4}\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}} \\
    &= \sqrt{a^2\left(1+\dfrac{1}{4}\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)} \\
    &= a\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}} \\
    &= a\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{8}+\dfrac{1+\cos\alpha}{8}} \\
    &= \dfrac{a\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}$$

4. Notice that because, out of properties of rhombus, the intersection point $O$ of diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ bisects them, $AO=OC$, and $BO=OD$. This implies that, becuase $AM_1=\dfrac{1}{4}AC$, $M_1O = AO-AM_1 = AM_1 = \dfrac{a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$.
5. Consider the triangle $OBM_1$. It is a right triangle, because, from properties of rhombus, the diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular. We know $BO=\dfrac{BD}{2}=a\sin\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$. We also know $OM_1=\dfrac{a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$. Then we can find hypotenuse $BM_1$ by applying Pythagorean Theorem:
   $$\begin{align*}
       BM_1 &= \sqrt{BO^2+M_1O^2} \\
       &= \sqrt{\left(a\sin\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)^2} \\
       &= \sqrt{a^2\sin^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}+\dfrac{a^2}{4}\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}} \\
       &= \sqrt{a^2\left(\sin^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)} \\
       &= a\sqrt{\sin^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}
   \end{align*}$$
   We now apply the half angle trigonometric identities in order to simplify the expression inside the root:
   $$\begin{align*}
       \sin^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}
       &= \dfrac{1-\cos\alpha}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1+\cos\alpha}{2} \\
       &= \dfrac{1-\cos\alpha}{2}+\dfrac{1+\cos\alpha}{8} \\
       &= \dfrac{4(1-\cos\alpha)}{4\cdot 2}+\dfrac{1+\cos\alpha}{8} \\
       &= \dfrac{4-4\cos\alpha}{8}+\dfrac{1+\cos\alpha}{8} \\
       &= \dfrac{4-4\cos\alpha+1+\cos\alpha}{8} \\
       &= \dfrac{5-3\cos\alpha}{8}
   \end{align*}$$
   And this gives us the final form of an expression for the hypotenuse:
   $$BM_1
       = a\sqrt{\dfrac{5-3\cos\alpha}{8}}
       = \dfrac{a\sqrt{5-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
6. Now consider another right triangle $BMM_1$ (it is a right triangle because $MM_1\perp (ABC)$, which implies it's perpendicular to each line in $(ABC)$). We know both of its legs, so we now apply Pythagorean Theorem to find the hypotenuse $BM$:
   $$\begin{align*}
       BM
       &= \sqrt{MM_1^2 + BM_1^2} \\
       &= \sqrt{a^2+\left(\dfrac{a\sqrt{5-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)^2} \\
       &= \sqrt{a^2+\dfrac{a^2(5-3\cos\alpha)}{8}} \\
       &= \sqrt{a^2\left(1+\dfrac{5-3\cos\alpha}{8}\right)} \\
       &= a\sqrt{\dfrac{13-3\cos\alpha}{8}} \\
       &= \dfrac{a\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}
   \end{align*}$$
7. Consider the triangle $AMB$. Let's find its semiperimeter.
   $$\begin{align*}
       p
       &= \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left(a+\dfrac{a\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{a\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
       &= \dfrac{a}{2}\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
       &= \dfrac{a(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha})}{4\sqrt{2}}
   \end{align*}$$
8. Now we apply Heron's formula to find its area:
   $$S = \sqrt{p(p-AB)(p-AM)(p-BM)}$$

To not overflow the whole place with the huge stack of TeX, we'll calculate and simplify each difference separately:

$$\begin{align*}
    p-AB
    &= \dfrac{a(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha})}{4\sqrt{2}}-a \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-4\sqrt{2}\right) \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-2\sqrt{2}\right)
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
    p-AM
    &= \dfrac{a(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha})}{4\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{a\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}} \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-2\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}\right) \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}\right)
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
    p-BM
    &= \dfrac{a(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha})}{4\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{a\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}} \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-2\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right) \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{9+\cos\alpha}-\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Now we find the simplified form of the expression under the square root:

$$\begin{align*}
    p(p-AB)(p-AM)(p-BM)
    &= \left(\dfrac{a}{4\sqrt{2}}\right)^4\left(272-16\cos^2\alpha\right) \\
    &= \dfrac{a^4(272-16\cos^2\alpha)}{1024}
\end{align*}$$

And now we find the area:

$$S
    = \sqrt{\dfrac{a^4(272-16\cos^2\alpha)}{1024}}
    = \dfrac{4a^2\sqrt{17-\cos^2\alpha}}{32}
    = \dfrac{a^2\sqrt{17-\cos^2\alpha}}{8}$$

*A pretty nice number to see. I expected worse.*

9. Now we find the altitude $MK$ by using the altitude formula:
   $$MK = h_{AB}
       = \dfrac{2S}{AB}
       = \dfrac{2a^2\sqrt{17-\cos^2\alpha}}{8a}
       = \dfrac{a\sqrt{17-\cos^2\alpha}}{4}$$

*One down!*

10. As $MM_1\perp AC$ and $AC\perp BD$, then by theorem of three perpendiculars $MO\perp BD$. As $BO=BD$, the triangle $MBD$ has segment $MO$ as a median. But $MO\perp BD$, thus $MO$ is also the altitude. Therefore, triangle $MBD$ is isosceles with $DM=BM=\dfrac{a\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}$.
11. Now consider another right triangle $MM_1C$. We know both of its legs, so we now apply Pythagorean Theorem to find the hypotenuse $CM$:

$$\begin{align*}
    CM
    &= \sqrt{MM_1^2+M_1C^2} \\
    &= \sqrt{a^2+\left(\dfrac{3a}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)^2} \\
    &= \sqrt{a^2+\dfrac{9a^2}{4}\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}} \\
    &= \sqrt{a^2\left(1+\dfrac{9}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}\right)} \\
    &= a\sqrt{\dfrac{8}{8}+\dfrac{9+9\cos\alpha}{8}} \\
    &= \dfrac{a\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}$$

12. Consider the triangle $DMC$. We now find its semiperimeter:
    $$\begin{align*}
        p
        &= a+\dfrac{a\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{a\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}} \\
        &= \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right) \\
        &= \dfrac{a\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}
    \end{align*}$$
13. Now we apply Heron's formula to find its area:
    $$S = \sqrt{p(p-CD)(p-CM)(p-DM)}$$

Again, to not overflow the whole place with the huge stack of TeX, we'll calculate and simplify each difference separately:

$$\begin{align*}
    p-CD
    &= \dfrac{a\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}-a \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-2\sqrt{2}\right) \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right)
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
    p-CM
    &= \dfrac{a\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{a\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}} \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}\right) \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right)
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
    p-DM
    &= \dfrac{a\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{a\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}} \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}-\sqrt{13-3\cos\alpha}\right) \\
    &= \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17+9\cos\alpha}\right)
\end{align*}$$

...and here I am, stuck with this giant product under the square root without any real idea on how to simplify it nicely and/or continue. My idea was to find all sides of the triangle $KML$, and then use Cosine Theorem to find the angle $KML$, which would solve the problem.

...so, any ideas on how to continue this?

Comment: I think you could instead compute $$KM_1=AM_1\sin{\alpha\over2}={1\over2}a\cos{\alpha\over2}\sin{\alpha\over2}={1\over4}a\sin\alpha$$ and $LM_1=3KM_1$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Then why do we have $L$, $K$, and $M_1$ belonging to one line?

Comment: Because $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes, but their parallel nature doesn't really prove that some point $M_1$ (which isn't even the intersection point of diagonals) lies on the same line as bases of perpendiculars dropped from a point outside of the plane.

Comment: Do you know the theorem of three perpendiculars? https://www.math-only-math.com/theorem-of-three-perpendiculars.html